# Swift: Parsing HTML and preserving new lines

Tags: swift

I am given the following HTML code and need to parse it into plain text. I have tried using HTML parsers such as SwiftSoup and Kanna but both are giving me somewhat, not so ideal results, ie the break lines are not properly preserved.

```
//HTML that needs to be parsed
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div dir="ltr">
   <div dir="ltr">
    <div dir="ltr">
     <div dir="ltr">
      <div dir="ltr">
       <div>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>
        <br>
       </div>
      <div dir="ltr">
       <br clear="all">
       <div>
        <div dir="ltr" class="gmail_signature">
         <div dir="ltr">
          <font><font><font><font>Yours Sincerely</font></font></font></font>
          <div>
           <font><font><font><font>Tony Stark</font></font></font></font>
          </div>
          <div>
           <font><font><font><font>CEO, Stark Industries</font></font></font></font>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>


//HTML Parsers 
//SwiftSoup
do {
    let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(html2)
    print(try doc.text())

} catch let error {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}

//Kanna
let doc = try? HTML(html: html2, encoding: .utf8)
print(doc?.body?.text ?? "")

//Results
//SwiftSoup
https://www.google.com Yours Sincerely Tony Stark CEO, Stark Industries

//Kanna
https://www.google.comYours SincerelyTony StarkCEO, Stark Industries
```

The ideal result should be something like `https://www.google.com\n\nYours Sincerely\nTony Stark\nCEO, Stark Industries` so that it appears like this:

```
https://www.google.com 

Yours Sincerely
Tony Stark
CEO, Stark Industries
```

Does anyone have an alternative? Note that the HTML that I receive will include many different structures, so I will have to address it generically.

Comment: Line breaks in HTML don't mean anything. You get a line break from `<br>` and `<p>` (and maybe `<div>`) tags, not newlines in the source.

Comment: @rmaddy have edited the title to state to preserve new lines instead.

Comment: That's the same thing. New lines and line breaks are the same thing. My comment still applies.

Comment: @rmaddy so you mean its impossible to achieve the ideal result stated in my question?

Comment: That's how HTML parsers (and browsers) work. Newlines/line breaks are simply treated as spaces and two or more spaces together get converted to a single space. When you write HTML, if you want a line break you use the `<br>` tag, not a newline. That's why you are getting the results you are seeing. A real browser would give you line breaks from the `<br>` (and possibly the `<div>`) tags. So you need to do the same.